# XPath Query for method called in same class

Tags: java, xpath, xquery, pmd

I want to write a PMD rule where I want to check if any method with @Cachable annotation should not be called within the same class.

Code Eg:

```
public class BadExample{
      @Cachable
      public void meth1(){
      }
      public void meth2() {        
          meth1();
      }
}
```

My current XPath Query for this rule is as follows:

```
//BlockStatement //Statement //StatementExpression //PrimaryExpression //PrimaryPrefix //Name[@Image = //ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration[Annotation//MarkerAnnotation//Name[@Image='Cachable']] //MethodDeclaration //MethodDeclarator]
```

When I evaluate both sides of the expression individually they point to meth1. But the issue is LHS evaluates to meth1 [i.e. name of method] while RHS evaluates to meth1() [i.e. name along with parameters]. The idea is to compare method names along with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since argument lists are variable length (and may even include varargs), doing proper method matching by signature is currently not easily supported on XPath (it may be in the future, just like symboltable matching is provided).

Currently, this is better achieved with a Java Visitor rule. You can go over each `ClassScope` and for each method declaration validate if it's annotated as expected, and if so, check for it's usages within the current class.

For reference, you can check the [`AccessorMethodGenerationRule`](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/AccessorMethodGenerationRule.java), which does something similar:

1. it checks all `ClassScope` for members and methods (you should only check methods) [code](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/AccessorMethodGenerationRule.java#L25-L51)
2. checks if the method is private (in your case, if it's annotated with `@Cacheable`) [code](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/AccessorMethodGenerationRule.java#L55-L57)
3. checks if it's being called from within a different class (in your case, if it's the same class) [code](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/blob/master/pmd-java/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/rule/design/AccessorMethodGenerationRule.java#L59-L63)

Hopefully that should help.